# Knockout js app - not working

Tags: knockout.js

New to this and I can't get this simple knockout app to work. It should display

Hello, Planet Earth!

I am referencing: http://knockoutjs.com/examples/helloWorld.html

Here is when I run the index.html:

[image]

Is it not finding the knockout-3.4.2.js file?

Here is the console. Looks like there is an error.

[image]

Here's the index.html file":

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>

    <!-- Import the Knockout file. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Dans\Work 2\Tech\Web Dev\Javascript and jQuery\Knockout.js\Examples\knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>

    <!-- Import the JavaScript file. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='liveExample'>   
    <p>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName' /></p> 
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind='value: lastName' /></p> 
    <h2>Hello, <span data-bind='text: fullName'> </span>!</h2>  
   </div>  
</body>
```

Here's the viewmodel file - app.js file":

```
var ViewModel = function(first, last) {
    this.firstName = ko.observable(first);
    this.lastName = ko.observable(last);

    this.fullName = ko.computed(function() {
        return this.firstName() + " " + this.lastName();
    }, this);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel("Planet", "Earth"));
```

Here's where I have it stored:

[image]

Comment: Can you use C:\.... for a src? What happens if you use a CDN like https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js ?

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser console? (ctrl-shift-i)

Comment: I tried the CDN..it did NOT change the behavior.

Comment: Looks like there is an error..I included it above.

Comment: Try moving your app.js import below the html body in a new script block.

Comment: Moving the app.js worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the app.js is being loaded in the `<head>` section it will be loaded before the body html exists which means there is nothing for knockout bind to at the time applyBindings is called.

```
<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>

    <!-- Import the Knockout file. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Dans\Work 2\Tech\Web Dev\Javascript and jQuery\Knockout.js\Examples\knockout-3.4.2.js">

    <!-- Import the JavaScript file. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
```

You'll need to move your import line below the html body, or wrap it in a delayed execution block like document.onload.

```
<head>
  <title>Hello World</title>

    <!-- Import the Knockout file. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Dans\Work 2\Tech\Web Dev\Javascript and jQuery\Knockout.js\Examples\knockout-3.4.2.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='liveExample'>   
    <p>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName' /></p> 
    <p>Last name: <input data-bind='value: lastName' /></p> 
    <h2>Hello, <span data-bind='text: fullName'> </span>!</h2>  
   </div>  
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    <!-- Import the JavaScript file. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</script>
```